# Is there a general formula for all the combinations of having at least a one in an N -tuple vector?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let **$x$**=$[x_1 x_2 ... x_N]$, $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $\bar{x}_i = 1-x_i; \forall i$ and $\sum_m^N x_m$ not necessarily one (independent events)

I'm trying to mathematically formulate the function g(**$x$**) for a general $N$.

For simplicity, let $N=2$ and the sum of the desired events should be as follows
\begin{equation}
g(x) = x_1x_2 + x_1\bar{x_2} + x_1\bar{x_2}
\end{equation}
and for $N=3$, it translates to 
\begin{equation}
g(x) = x_1x_2x_3 + x_1x_2\bar{x_3} + x_1\bar{x_2}x_3+ x_1\bar{x_2}\bar{x_3}+\bar{x}_1x_2x_3+ \bar{x}_1x_2\bar{x}_3+ \bar{x}_1\bar{x_2}x_3.
\end{equation}
Note that the case of all zeros (i.e., $\bar{x}_1\bar{x}_2\bar{x}_3$) shouldn't be considered.

Comment: If $\bar{x_i} = 0\; \forall i$ then why is your $N=2$ expression not just $g(x)=x_1x_2$?

Comment: My mistake, I edited the question. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression you want is
$$\prod_{i=1}^n (x_i + \bar{x_i}) -\prod_{i=1}^n \bar{x_i}$$
which simplifies to
$$1-\prod_{i=1}^n \bar{x_i}$$
For example, with $n=2$, you get
$$
g(x)
=
(x_1+\bar{x_1})(x_2+\bar{x_2})-\bar{x_1}\bar{x_2}
=
x_1x_2+x_1\bar{x_2}+\bar{x_1}x_2
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\,
$$
or equivalently, 
$$
g(x)=1-\bar{x_1}\bar{x_2}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\,
$$
and for $n=3$, you get
\begin{align*}
g(x)
&=
(x_1+\bar{x_1})(x_2+\bar{x_2})(x_3+\bar{x_3})-\bar{x_1}\bar{x_2}\bar{x_3}\\[4pt]
&=
x_1x_2x_3
+
x_1x_2\bar{x_3}
+
x_1\bar{x_2}x_3
+
x_1\bar{x_2}\bar{x_3}
+
\bar{x_1}x_2x_3
+
\bar{x_1}x_2\bar{x_3}
+
\bar{x_1}\bar{x_2}x_3
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
or equivalently, 
$$
g(x)=1-\bar{x_1}\bar{x_2}\bar{x_3}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I am not sure about the simplification part, since $x_i;\forall i$ are independent

Comment: But $x_i+\bar{x_i}=1$, for all $i$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, slipped my mind!